# Parsing GeoJson data in golang

Tags: json, go, geojson

I want to parse a JSON file that contains a feature collection of a country's regions.

I am using this package `https://github.com/tidwall/geojson`

I opened the file like this:

```
jsonFile, err := os.Open("filename.json")
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer jsonFile.Close()

data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

And then I parse the file using this:

```
obj, err := geojson.Parse(string(data), geojson.DefaultParseOptions)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

but it returns a single geojson.Object and I want a list of features

Can someone help me with this

Comment: Implementing custom GeoJSON structs is not all that hard. Check this out: https://engineering.kablamo.com.au/posts/2020/geometry.

The library you're using is an abstraction that doesn't seem to fit your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved

// open json file

```
jsonFile, err := os.Open(filename)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer jsonFile.Close()
```

// read the file

```
data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

// parse into a single geojson.Object

```
obj, err := geojson.Parse(string(data), geojson.DefaultParseOptions)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

// typecast geojson.Object into geojson.FeatureCollection

```
fc, ok := obj.(*geojson.FeatureCollection)
if !ok {
    return nil, errors.Newf(errors.Internal, nil, "cannot convert into feature collection")
}
```